# font awesome 5 brand icons not working

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome icons in a page I am developing, and while the `fas` icons work fine, the `fab` icons do not. Instead, with the `fab` icons, I get a blank square. I currently have both the Font Awesome CDN link and a link to the local `fontawesome-all.min.css` file. I have disabled AdBlock Plus, and I am using `http-server` as my development server. Here is a copy of the head and first section of my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Download</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Simonetta" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- banner section -->
        <section id="banner" class="bg-success">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row max-viewport align-items-center text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6 my-5 order-2 order-md-1">
                        <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 my-5 order-1 order-md-2">
                        <h1 class="text-danger text-uppercase">
                            <small>phone crasher</small> App
                        </h1>
                        <p class="lead text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-uppercase m-2"><i class="fab fa-apple mr-2"></i>Apple Store</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-uppercase m-2"><i class="fab fa-google mr-2"></i>Google Store</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>`
```

Comment: `Any suggestions?` : show us your code so we can trust you

Comment: `Here is the code one of the icons` --> we need full code that reproduce the issue to see what you did wrong

Comment: Show us your css/js imports

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the import for the brands.js file

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/brands.js" integrity="sha384-sCI3dTBIJuqT6AwL++zH7qL8ZdKaHpxU43dDt9SyOzimtQ9eyRhkG3B7KMl6AO19" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Please read their [docs](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js) (hint: click the "Brands" pill to include it)

Answer (score 0):

don't add the  twice sometimes causes problems.
and use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css